# ClassNotFoundException in Realm after enabling proguard

Tags: android, realm, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I am getting an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "io.realm.Realm"

In build.gradle minifyEnabled true.

proguard-rules.pro:

> -keep class io.realm.annotations.RealmModule
>
> -keep @io.realm.annotations.RealmModule class *
>
> -keep class io.realm.internal.Keep
>
> -keep @io.realm.internal.Keep class *
>
> -dontwarn javax.**
>
> -keep class io.realm.{ *; }
>
> -keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject
>
> -keep public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject { *; }

Any idea?

Comment: please before implement pro-guard read the documentation

Comment: If this is the same as what we see on https://realm.io/, they claim you don't need to do this: "A ProGuard configuration is provided as part of the Realm library. This means that you don’t need to add any Realm specific rules to your ProGuard configuration." That is, I suspect tweaking the proguard rules will not help solve this problem, as it is related to something else.

Comment: Let's see your project and app build.gradle files.

Comment: Which version of Realm are you using? Which API version device is this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'll have to replace this rule:

```
-keep class io.realm.{ *; }
```

With this one:

```
-keep class io.realm.** { *; }
```

Everything else that starts with io.realm can then be removed.

Why? The first rule you have here is invalid. The second one will keep everything in io.realm including any sub-packages, methods and fields. This means that it will override all of the other rules.